# Error handling in express based on how a resource is called?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express.

I am handling a Get request like below.

```
router.get('/user', user.getSessionInfo);
```

On client side I am using Angularjs.

I want to customize my error handling in nodejs based upon how a resource is being called, i.e. when /user is called via an $http call or directly from browser url so that I can return(if an error happens) either a json error obj or an error page(html).

I tried using req.xhr to decide whether the call is an ajax or not but I am getting false in both cases(*not getting X-Requested-With header via $http.get*)

So to achieve my functionality Can I depend upon

```
req.headers['accept'];
```

as from ajax call it will be

```
"application/json, text/plain, */*"
```

and when called from the browser url bar it will be

```
"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
```

Is my way the best or there is a better way of handling it?

Comment: If you're going to have different types of return values for different callers, you should have the caller specify what type of return value they want rather than guessing based on how it was called.  That becomes a non-documented behavior based on an implicit behavior and should be frowned upon in any API.  Instead have the caller specify an argument either in the URL path itself or in a query parameter that tells your server what type of error response they want.  Don't guess.  Make it explicit.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying I guess I need to rename some routes i.e. from user to user.json and check for .json in my errorHandler in order to display error in correct format. I asked this question because of my generic errorHandler as there are some routes which always return html pages and their error will be html pages. Thanks again for replying.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way,use query param(dot extension) to decide resource type:

```
 GET /api/user.json
 GET /api/user.html
 GET /api/user.xml
```

and it seems than this solution is more complicated to achieve in Express.

Comment: thanks for replying I guess I need to rename some routes here.

Comment: so should I use req.path and then extract .json part and decide the response of error?

Answer (score 0):

req.xhr was removed in angular. Read here why removed and how to get it back

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3a75b1124d062f64093a90b26630938558909e8d

Comment: I didn't know it. Thanks for mentioning it.